# How to search for an installed application in linux

Tags: java, find

rpm -e jdk-1.6.0_17-fcs
error: Failed dependencies:
    jdk is needed by (installed) xyz.i586
I tried to search for xyz.i586
find / -name xyz.i586

but no result.

Comment: It would help if you listed what linux distro you are using. From your question we can only assume it is rpm based (redhat, fedora, centOS?)

Answer (score 1):

did you try the -q option ?

```
$ rpm -q jdk

jdk-1.6.0_34-fcs.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using -q flag

```
$ rpm -q jdk
```

I would use -qa flag then grep output

```
$ rpm -qa | grep jdk
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.49.1.11.4.el6_3.x86_64
```

Since it will cast a wider net and list java packages that may not begin with "jdk"

Answer (score 0):

(Oh, you are using an old JDK version, I understand you want to uninstall it.)

To find out whether `xyz` is installed I would use:

```
rpm -q -a | grep xyz
```

But you **already know** `xyz` is installed: `jdk` rejects being uninstalled because it is needed by `xyz`.

Maybe you want to know where `xyz` is or what it is?. Use this to list all files of package `xyz`:

```
rpm -q -l xyz
```

and this to show a description of `xyz`:

```
rpm -q -i xyz
```

If you don't need `xyz` you can uninstall both `xyz` and `jdk` as follows:

```
rpm -e xyz jdk
```

Answer (score -1):

For where the program was installed (including all of the supporting files, so it can be a long list that you would need to search through)

dpkg-query -L firefox

For the menu item containing the package, look for a file in /usr/share/menu in the output of dpkg-query:

dpkg-query -L firefox | grep /usr/share/menu

In that file you should find "section=". The string after that text should indicate where in the menu system you would find the link to the application.

For information about what categories Ubuntu put the package into, you might try:

aptitude show firefox

Comment: dpkg and aptitude probably won't be useful since the OP is referencing missing rpm's